# spaCy: How to write named entities to an existing Doc object using some loaded model for this?

Tags: python, nlp, token, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I created a `Doc` object from a custom list of tokens according to documentation like so:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc

nlp = spacy.load("my_ner_model")
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=["Hello", ",", "world", "!"])
```

How do I write named entities tags to `doc` with my NER model now?

I tried to do `doc = nlp(doc)`, but that didn't work for me raising a `TypeError`.

I can't just join my list of words into a plain text to do `doc = nlp(text)` as usual because in this case `spaCy` splits some words in my texts into two tokens which I can not accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the NER component from your loaded model and call it directly on the constructed `Doc`:

```
doc = nlp.get_pipe("ner")(doc)
```

You can inspect a list of all the available components in the pipeline with `nlp.pipe_names` and call them individually this way. The tokenizer is always the first element of the pipeline when you call `nlp()` and it isn't included in this list, which only has the components that both take and return a `Doc`.